# How do I compute profit from two lists in python containing floats?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-loops

```
aapl = [ 10, 154.12 ]
goog = [  2, 812.56 ]
tsla = [ 12, 342.12 ]
fb   = [ 18, 209.0  ]

portfolio = [ aapl, goog, tsla, fb ]
market = [ 198.84, 1217.93, 267.66, 179.06 ]

def pnl(market, portfolio):
    market = 0
    for i in range(len(portfolio)):
        for j in range(len(portfolio[i])):
            market += market[i] - portfolio[j]
    print(market)
```

e.g in this case, i need to subtract it like this
(198.84 - 154.12) + (1217.93 - 812.56) ..... and so on.
When i run this, it does not show any output in console??
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the function you defined. You can call it like this:

```
pnl(market, portfolio)
```